# Find all SPD workflows in site collection

Tags: workflow

I am migrating a sharepoint farm and need to update all SPD workflows in the migrated site collection. **I need to get a list of all SPD workflows that exist in the site collection** so I can update URLs, email addresses etc.

I know I can open each site in SPD and check for workflows from there - however, there are over a 100 sites and subsites and I'm sure there is a better way to list all workflows (SQL query, Powershell script).

Any help would be appreciated, 
Greg

Update:
Ok, so a quick and dirty way of listing all workflows is to run the following SQL query on the content DB

```
SELECT dirname, leafname 
FROM allDocs 
WHERE LeafName LIKE '%.xoml'
```

If anyone has a better way (PowerShell anyone?) let me know.

Comment: When I try to run this script on my MOSS SP 2007 Service Pack 3, Win Server 2003 system, with PowerShell v1, I get the error New-Object : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Property'.
At C:\Documents and Settings\sa_sps\My Documents\WindowsPowerShell\listworkflow.ps1:24 char:59
+ New-Object PSObject -Property <<<< $hash | Sort-Object Does anyone know of a fix for this in the powershell v1 environment?

Answer (score 12):

You can do this using Powershell. Loop through all sites in your site collection, then all lists, then all workflow associations.

```
$site = Get-SPSite("your-site-url");
$site.AllWebs | foreach { $_.Lists | foreach { $_.WorkflowAssociations | foreach { 
  write-host "Site:" $_.ParentWeb.Url ", List:" $_.ParentList.Title ", Workflow:" $_.Name
} } }
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this solves your problem, make sure you check it as your selected answer. That will help folks later.

Comment: Or failing that, maybe somebody will come along and at least give it an upvote...  +1

Comment: All who replied... Say, the poster said he was "migrating", strongly implying that what he needs to examine is a SharePoint 2007 farm. That said, is the Powershell script offered valid? That is, out-of-the-box SharePoint 2007 DOES have Powershell, but NOT "SharePoint-SAVVY" Powershell, so is the cmdlet suggested - "Get-SPSite" even VALID without somehow enhancing his SharePoint 2007 install with a .ps1 file which teaches it how to perform a Get-SPSite cmdlet? I'm facing the same challenge with a client's SP2007 farm, and don't see how the OOTB PowerShell available in my SP2007 farm is going to

Comment: Hi!  Is this targeting 2007?  
$site = Get-SPSite("http://myURL");
$site.AllWebs | foreach { $_.Lists | foreach { $_.WorkflowAssociations | foreach { 
  write-host "Site:" $_.ParentWeb.Url ", List:" $_.ParentList.Title ", Workflow:" $_.Name
} } }

Comment: This is for SP2010. For 2007 look in the comments of the answer to this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/31491/how-can-i-list-all-workflows-and-associations

Answer (score 2):

Check this code,  i dont remember but find it somewhere in the WEB:
It listing all workflows inside one site collection and generating CSV table.

```
#Load SharePoint 2007 Assemblies
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c") | out-null

$siteurl="http://site.domain.com"
$site=new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteurl)

#Initialize Workflow Count variable
$workflowcount = 0

#Foreach loop to loop through all webs, and lists with workflow associations, and exclude workflows that have previous versions and write findings to .csv file.

function Get-Workflows()
{
    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
    {
            foreach($list in $web.Lists)
            {
                foreach($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
                {
                        if ($wf.Name -notlike "*Previous Version*")
                        {
                            $hash = @{"[URL]"=$web.Url;"[List Name]"=$list.Title;"[Workflow]"=$wf.Name}
                             New-Object PSObject -Property $hash | Sort-Object

                        }
                }
            }
    }
}

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
    foreach($list in $web.Lists)
    {
        foreach($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
        {
            if ($wf.Name -notlike "*Previous Version*")
            {
               $workflowcount += 1
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-Workflows | Export-csv E:\workflows.csv
"Workflow Count " + $workflowcount >> E:\workflows.csv

$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: How is this code differentiate the list of workflows returned by this code are workflow build out of the box workflows or SPD build workflows?

Answer (score 0):

Workflow Report -

This script genenrates list of all site and list workflows in a given site collection url. It captures the below properites

1. Web Url
2. Site workflows count
3. List workflows count

   (the below properites are shown in a different row)
4. List title (if #3 has count > 0)
5. Workflow Name
6. Tasks list of the workflow
7. WF History list of the workflow
8. Current running instances
9. Create date
10. WF last modified date

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/List-of-all-workflows-in-a-ffa0b355

```
    if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
    {
        Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
    }
    
    Function WriteWFDetails($wfAssociations, $wfType, $listTitle, $OutputFile, $includePreviousVersions) 
    {
        if($includePreviousVersions) {
            $wfAssociations = ($wfAssociations | Sort-Object Name)
        }
        else {
            $wfAssociations = ($wfAssociations | ?{-Not ($_.Name -like "*Previous Version*")} | Sort-Object Name)
        }
        foreach($wfAssociation in $wfAssociations) {
            #$record =",,,$wfType,`"$($listTitle)`",`"$($wfAssociation.Name)`",`"$($wfAssociation.TaskListTitle)`",`"$($wfAssociation.HistoryListTitle)`","
            #$record += "$($wfAssociation.RunningInstances),$($wfAssociation.Created),$($wfAssociation.Modified)"
            Add-Content $OutputFile $record
        }
    }
    
    Function AllWorkflows($siteUrl, $OutputFile, $includePreviousVersions)
    {
        $siteColl  = Get-SPSite $siteUrl
        Set-Content $OutputFile "WebUrl,SiteWFCount,ListWFCount,SiteWF or ListWF?,ListName,WorkflowName,TaskList,HistoryList,RunningInstances,Created,Modified"
    
        foreach($web in $siteColl.AllWebs)
        {
            $webUrl = if($web.IsRootWeb) { "$($web.Url) -- RootWeb" } else {  $web.Url }
    
            if($includePreviousVersions) {
                $siteWFCount = $web.WorkflowAssociations.Count
                $listWFCount = $web.Lists.WorkflowAssociations.Count
            }
            else {
                $siteWFCount = ($web.WorkflowAssociations | ? {-Not ($_.Name -like "*Previous Version*")}).Count
                $listWFCount = ($web.Lists.WorkflowAssociations | Select Name | ? {-Not ($_.Name -like "*Previous Version*")}).Count
            }
    
            if($listWFCount -gt 0 -or $siteWFCount -gt 0) {
                #$record = "`"$webUrl`",$siteWFCount,$listWFCount"
                Add-Content $OutputFile $record;
            
                WriteWFDetails $web.WorkflowAssociations "SiteWF" "" $OutputFile $includePreviousVersions
    
                foreach($list in ($web.Lists | ? {$_.WorkflowAssociations.Count -gt 0}))
                {
                    WriteWFDetails $list.WorkflowAssociations "ListWF" $list.Title $OutputFile $includePreviousVersions
                }
            }
            $web.Dispose()
        }
        $siteColl.Dispose()
    }
    
    #parameter 3 - pass $TRUE to include previous workflow versions
    AllWorkflows "<your site collection url here>" "C:\Temp\WorkflowReport.csv" $FALSE
```