# How can I list all workflows and associations?

Tags: 2007, workflow

How can I list all workflows and associations? I can find the number through the workflows page in the site collection administration, but i need to find the associations of each...

This is for MOSS 2007!

Comment: do u need to get the associations of only lists or content types too?

Comment: just the workflows and what their list/library associations are in moss2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use Powershell script to get all the workflow associations for all lists of the site.

Sample code might look like this -

**UPDATED CODE** for checking a particular list-

```
$siteCollectionUrl = "Your Site Collection URL"
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteCollectionUrl)    
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs)
{
 $listToCheck = "List Name"
 foreach ($list in $web.Lists) 
 { 
  if($list.Title -eq $listToCheck)
  {
   write-host "List Title -->" $list.Title
   foreach ($wf in $list.WorkFlowAssociations) 
    {      
     write-host "Workflow -->" $wf.Name
    }
  }
 }
}
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

Comment: this is for 2010, which I use powershell a bunch! But I need a solution for 2007.

Comment: In 2007 this shows:


- GAC    Version        Location  
- ---    -------        --------  
- True   v2.0.50727     C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_M  
- List Title --> Converted Forms  
- List Title --> Form Templates  
- List Title --> List Template Gallery  
- List Title --> Master Page Gallery  
- List Title --> Reporting Metadata  
- List Title --> Reporting Templates  
- List Title --> Site Template Gallery  
- List Title --> User Information List  
- List Title --> Web Part Gallery  
Any thoughts?

Comment: its populating all lists even though it does not have workflows. I have updated the answer for you to check any particular list for you. Good Luck.

Comment: That is all the workflows in the site, but I'm saying what about all the workflows in the whole site collection, how can I loop through all the sites and subsites?

Comment: For all sites replace $web = $site.OpenWeb() with "foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs){" and add a "}" at the end

Comment: Shouldn't the script be disposing of objects, or is that just visual studio?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Updated code with disposing objects for you. :)

Comment: Thanks so much! What happens when you don't dispose in powershell? How long does it stay in memory?

Comment: check this post Mike. Its exactly what you've asked- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999858/how-bad-is-it-to-not-dispose-in-powershell

Comment: The $web.Dispose() should be moved up one line so it's inside the loop

Comment: This worked for me in 2007 [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity]::RunWithElevatedPrivileges( { 
$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteCollectionUrl)  
"Workflows Report" | Out-File -FilePath $OutputFilePath
foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 
{foreach ($list in $web.Lists)  
 {foreach ($wf in $list.WorkFlowAssociations)  
    {"Web Url > " + $web.URL + " ; List Title > " + $list.Title + "; Workflow > " + $wf.Name | Out-File -Append -FilePath $OutputFilePath
    } 
 } 
 $web.Dispose() 
} 
$site.Dispose() 
});

Answer (score 2):

[SPWeb.WorkflowTemplates;](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.workflowtemplates%28v=office.12%29.aspx) gives you a list of all workflow in a site.

[SPWorkflowManager.CountWorkflowAssociations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.workflow.spworkflowmanager.countworkflowassociations%28v=office.12%29.aspx) gives you the count of all associations in a Site Collection

But to get all the associations you have to loop through all Content Types, Lists and Content Types in lists and look at the WorkflowAssociations property

If you want to use Deepu's PowerShell on 2007 the replace line 1 with

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$site = [Microsoft.Sharepoint.SPSite]("http://sharepoint")
$web = $site.OpenWeb()
```

But remeber that his script will not show workflows associated with ContentTypes or ContentTypes in lists

Comment: Ok, that's half the work, but I was hoping to take out the programming aspect. I wish there was powershell for 2007 that I can use a script like Deepu Nair posted...

Comment: PowerShell tip added

Comment: the powershell works, what a charm to have powershell on my 2007 box!! Thank you so much! However, look below it's not giving me what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Workflow Manager web part on http://sp2010adminpack.codeplex.com/. Should work on 2007.

Comment: Is there any way, i can get the same functionality in  JSOM, only javascript/ecma script